# Can you identify this plane? Picture from ca1942, maybe Taylorcraft

Tags: aircraft-identification, airplane

[image]This was my grandfather's plane, picture taken, I believe, in 1942.  My grandparents are long gone and I have no one to confirm the ID of this plane, but from internet searches, it looks like a Taylorcraft BC-65.  Would the experts out there please weigh in?

Possible Taylorcraft BC-65

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is a Taylorcraft BC-65, or possibly a BL-65.  The configuration of the wing struts and the struts visible inside the windscreen are all consistent with B-series Taylorcraft.  The greater depth of the windscreen and side windows helps distinguish it from later variants such as the BC12-65. The small trim surface visible ***below*** the horizontal tail is further clue that this is a BC-65 or BL-65.  Here are some links to photos of other BC-65s or BL-65s with the same trim surface:

http://russellw.com/photoalbum/photo_query_results.asp?qModel=eBL-65 (scroll down to 4th photo)

https://www.aircraft.com/aircraft/201009513/n23683-1939-taylorcraft-bl-65
https://www.airliners.net/photo/Untitled/Taylorcraft-BC-65/623696
https://www.airliners.net/photo/Untitled/Taylorcraft-BC-65/5214477
https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Taylorcraft_BC-65_%28N24393%29.jpg
https://www.skytamer.com/Taylorcraft_B.html

Comment: Now, if someone finds a photo of a BC12-65 with that same trim surface, I'll have to modify this answer-- (I couldn't find one)-- but even in that case I still believe it is the older BC-65 or BL-65.